# How to use OpenGL (ES) through Python

Tags: python, opengles

I recently got my Pi and thought to give OpenGL another try. So I searched around for OpenGL Python modules as this would be my first choice as language. Although I'm aware that there are differences between the basic OpenGL and OpenGL ES I tried PyOpenGL without any luck. Then I found [pyopengles](https://github.com/peterderivaz/pyopengles) but as I am very new to OpenGL I was overwhelmed by the complexity of the examples.

My question is, is [pyopengles](https://github.com/peterderivaz/pyopengles) the standard way to go if I want to use OpenGL ES from within Python or are there any other modules and where can I find a step by step tutorial for the proposed module(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pyopengles is probably the best choice for the moment, it's certainly not very mature yet, but is quite functional. It would be nice to see some of it wrapped in a more OO fashion, but it's good for learning the raw mechanics of opengl es if that's what you're interested in.

I found this page very helpful when I was trying to get to grips with pyopengles on my pi -

http://blog.db-in.com/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-1/

Once you understand the opengles state machine concept it becomes a bit easier, the problem is that raw opengles is very dissimilar to the 'pythonic' way of programming. As I said, I'm looking forward to a more OO wrapper around opengles on the pi myself.

Comment: I was **JUST** linking that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ctypes implementation of OpenGL ES.

https://github.com/stephanh42/rpigl